# Express function as a variable

Tags: php, function, variables

I dont know exactly how to put this. I have this function:

```
    protected function _do_thumb($temaid)
 { 
   $firstPost  = $this->registry->topics->getPostById( $temaid );
   preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $firstPost['post'], $match);   
   return $match[1];     
 }

[...]

while ( $i = $this->DB->fetch() )
        {
            $forum = $this->registry->class_forums->forum_by_id[ $i['forum_id'] ];

            if ( $this->registry->permissions->check( 'read', $forum ) != TRUE )
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ( $forum['password'] != "" )
            {
                continue;
            } 

            $to_echo .= $this->_parseTemplate( $row, array ( 
                'topic_title'    => str_replace( '&#', '&amp;#', $i['title'] ),
                                                             'topic_id'       => $i['tid'],
                                                             'topic_link'     => "showtopic=".$i['tid'],
                                                             'forum_title'    => htmlspecialchars($forum['name']),
                                                             'forum_id'       => $i['forum_id'],
                                                             'last_poster_id' => $i['last_poster_id'],
                                                             'last_post_name' => $i['last_poster_name'],
                                                             'last_post_time' => $this->registry->getClass('class_localization')->getDate( $i['last_post'] , 'LONG', 1 ),
                                                             'timestamp'      => $i['start_date'],
                                                             'starter_id'     => $i['starter_id'],
                                                             'starter_name'   => $i['starter_name'],
                                                             'board_url'      => $this->settings['board_url'],
                                                             'board_name'     => $this->settings['board_name'],
                                                             'rfc_date'       => date( 'j\-M\-Y', $i['start_date']),
                'thumb'         => $this->_do_thumb($i['topic_firstpost'])
                ) ) . "\r\n";
        }
```

$firstPost is supposed to produce a value result of another function. The problem here is that that function seems to stop halfway the whole loop so it returns an incomplete result, only the first element of a list. $forum however works fine because it is expressed as a variable so I believe the solution might be to express $topic in the same way. Something like this:

```
$this->registry->topics->getPostById[ $temaid ];
```

However, I dont know how I ought do it. Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is intentional first? `$fetch_sql()`

Comment: Yes, I abridged the function because its much more complex than that. But simply put its that it.

Comment: Can you add full code?  `$some_stuff .= array ('forum_title'=> $forum['name'], 'thumb'=> $topic['firstpost']);` is not valid

Comment: You cannot concatinate array to string. Inside loop, you try to concatinate array to $some_stuff

Comment: I cant include the full code because its way too much. I might have a typo on my code here because its just an example but you can be sure everything in the actual code is right. My only problem is with the value of $topic.

Comment: imo, _do not post var_dump output in comments unless it is small_. ;-/ Also, the output is for you to use to help you to work out what is happening... You may decide to add it to your question if you think it may assist us.... imo, debugging (1): before `$topic = ...`. `var_dump($i, $i['tid']);`. Immediately after: `var_dump($topic);`.

Comment: I did it but its way too long to post it here. What should I do?

Comment: The values and all that are okay. The problem is the way the function behaves. By expressing it like this: $this->registry->topics->getPostById( $temaid ); it interrupts the whole script after one loop so the only way to stop that is by having this instead: $this->registry->topics->getPostById[$temaid ]; but this variable is not defined so it produces nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getBostById()` and  `$i = $this->DB->fetch()` in while loop where you call getPostById(), they both use `$this->DB` to store information from Database.

And when called `getPostById()`, it overrides information inside of `$this->DB` and moves hidden pointer to the end. This function returns POST data from database, and also uses something like `$i = $this->DB->fetch()` for this. Therefore pointer to data moves to the end.

Next, time when `$i = $this->DB->fetch()` called, it sees pointer at the end, and stop looping.

Solution is, when fetching result from database, don't override it. There for cache them before calling `getPostById`:

```
//while ( $i = $this->DB->fetch() )
$items = array();
$counter = 0 ;
while ($i = $this->DB->fetch()) {
   $items[$counter++] = $i;
}
foreach ( $items as $i ){
        $forum = $this->registry->class_forums->forum_by_id[ $i['forum_id'] ];

        if ( $this->registry->permissions->check( 'read', $forum ) != TRUE )
        {
            continue;
        }

        if ( $forum['password'] != "" )
        {
            continue;
        } 

        $to_echo .= $this->_parseTemplate( $row, array ( 
            'topic_title'    => str_replace( '&#', '&amp;#', $i['title'] ),
                                                         'topic_id'       => $i['tid'],
                                                         'topic_link'     => "showtopic=".$i['tid'],
                                                         'forum_title'    => htmlspecialchars($forum['name']),
                                                         'forum_id'       => $i['forum_id'],
                                                         'last_poster_id' => $i['last_poster_id'],
                                                         'last_post_name' => $i['last_poster_name'],
                                                         'last_post_time' => $this->registry->getClass('class_localization')->getDate( $i['last_post'] , 'LONG', 1 ),
                                                         'timestamp'      => $i['start_date'],
                                                         'starter_id'     => $i['starter_id'],
                                                         'starter_name'   => $i['starter_name'],
                                                         'board_url'      => $this->settings['board_url'],
                                                         'board_name'     => $this->settings['board_name'],
                                                         'rfc_date'       => date( 'j\-M\-Y', $i['start_date']),
            'thumb'         => $this->_do_thumb($i['topic_firstpost'])
            ) ) . "\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: Its already a defined function. The problem as I said is not that but the fact that it has () instead of []. Thats why $forum works alright s Im trying to do the same with $topic.

Comment: You said, might be its return wrong data. So you looking for []. But what you want to get with function: Posts or topics? If you try to get posts, then you are using topic ID. So it might be wrong.

Comment: I know it looks odd but its correct. Its supposed to return the first post of the given topic ID.

Comment: getPostById() function requires ID of post as argument (not Id of topic). If you want to get post of given topic ID, use getPosts, as shown in answer.

Comment: Okay, now that I realize you seem to understand IP Board I can explain you in more detail. Do you know an old tool called ssi.php included in the IPB package? It displays the latest topics in xml format. It displays title, author, link and some other things but no post content which Im trying to have displayed as well. I will update my question with some more of the actual code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111399/discussion-between-medet-ahmetson-atabayev-and-cain-nuke).